# How do I find the hook names for the WooCommerce stylesheets

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want the WooCommerce Stylesheet to be loaded after my custom stylesheet, so that WooCommerce does not override any of my custom CSS entries.  To achieve this, I have entered the following into my functions.php file:

```
function theme_name_script_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpb-fa', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css', array() );
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/invictus-custom-java.js', array(), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_style('custom_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/invictus-custom-style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_script_enqueue' 2);

//WooCommerce Stylesheet(s)
remove_action( 'A', 'B' );
add_action( 'C', 'D', 1 );
```

As you can see, I have placed a higher priority for `theme_name_script_enqueue`, so that it loads after the WooCommerce stylesheets.  Regarding the second section of code, I want to remove the WooCommerce Stylesheets and then re-add them  with a lower priority as to ensure they load 1st.  Is anyone able to help me in identifying where I can find WooCommerce's hook names etc, so that I can enter the correct details within A, B, C and D?

Comment: did you check the new edit ? i have moved our discussion to chat. the link is in below comments. we can talk there if it still does not work for you.I am up for the next 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do that. Just enqueue your styles and make sure that the styles in your stylesheet are at the same or greater level of specificality then the woocommerce style sheet.

**General Rules:**

1. More specific selectors will override more general ones
2. Use !important where rule one does not work.

**Reference from w3org:**

https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#cascade

Comment: Thanks for this.  With this in mind, how would I remove the WooCommerce styles in the functions.php file?  I tried `remove_action( 'wp_dequeue_style', 'woocommerce-layout' );
remove_action( 'wp_dequeue_style', 'woocommerce-smallscreen' );
remove_action( 'wp_dequeue_style', 'woocommerce-general' );
` but this did not work.

Comment: Thanks for your time.  Your option works, however when I add the styles back, with a priority of 1, the WooCommerce stylesheets are still called after the custom stylesheets I created, which have a priority of 10.

Comment: no you need to add them with a higher priority try giving them a priority of 20 instead of 1. lower priority means earlier execution.

Comment: I added the following code `function sr_remove_default_stylesheet() 
{
    wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce-layout');
    wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce-smallscreen');
    wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce-general');
}
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sr_remove_default_stylesheet', 10);
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sr_remove_default_stylesheet', 10);` but to no success.  I changed the priorities for the custom stylesheet yet the WooCommerce stylesheet always overrides custom stylesheet.  I want the custom stylesheets to override ride the WooCommerce stylesheets. :-)

Comment: yes you do not need this line. remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sr_remove_default_stylesheet', 10); pasting the functions in functions.php as i have written in my answer will remove those styles.

Comment: I have also tried `add_filter( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sr_remove_default_stylesheet', 1000);` I have replaced 1000 with 1 but still no success.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138993/discussion-between-shazyriver-and-craig).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may be what you're looking for. Hope it helps!

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Comment: Thanks for this resource.  It was through this resource, where I found, I need to change the priority for `woocommerce_enqueue_styles`.  That said, I am still looking for the location/name of the action which this hooks into.  I have yet to find it but will update accordingly, when I do. :-)